# Why does "su - X" require password, but "sudo -u X bash" doesn't?

Tags: bash, redhat, sudo, su

I know "why" questions are dangerous :) I have sudo access on RHEL, and noticed this:

```
su - fred
Password:
```

(I don't know fred's password).

```
sudo -u fred bash
[fred] $
```

Is there a way to not need fred's password to do the `su`? Is there a reason to want that?

Comment: Which pair of commands are you asking about?  The ones in the question body?  Or the ones in the question title?

Comment: The ones in the question body. You don't seem to be able to change titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `sudo` uses privileges attached to the account you're running as, while `su` is more similar to logging in at a normal prompt as the user you're changing to.

Try `su root` as a regular user that doesn't have permissions in the `sudoers` file - you can use the `root` credentials to change to that user, regardless of your current user's rights.

Conversely, `sudo` and the permissions assigned in your `/etc/sudoers` file allow your current user to work as root without needing to know any password but your own.  For instance, add `sudo` to the front of your `su -u fred` command - fred's password is no longer needed, since the `su` is then running with root privleges.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` temporarily caches your passwords ... is this the case here?

Comment: That's true, but not quite relevant - I know *my* password, I don't know *fred's* password. (Entering my password in the first example didn't work)